# How to turn off Internet Explorer enhanced security settings in Azure

Tags: security, internet-explorer, configuration, internet-explorer-8, azure

My site is hosted on Azure. I need to programmatically turn off Internet Explorer's default **enhanced security configuration settings** whenever I repave or redeploy a new box on Azure.

How do I do this?

I found this article on another site http://jetlounge.net/blogs/teched/archive/2009/10/25/fix-ie-esc-won-t-turn-off-internet-explorer-enhanced-security.aspx. It included the following command line syntax, but on my local box I couldn't find the IEHARDEN.INF file it referred to. I also don't think this solution is Azure-specific.

```
rundll32.exe setupapi.dll,InstallHinfSection IESoftenAdmin 128 %windir%\inf\IEHARDEN.INF
```

I need to turn off these default hardening settings under **Azure** because I have a 3rd party IE screen capture DLL that needs to execute Javascript on webpages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [this approach](http://www.myexchangeworld.com/2010/12/script-to-disable-internet-explorer-ie-enhanced-security-configuration/), shaped in a [Windows Azure StartupTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) running in [Elevated execution context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh124132.aspx) will help you.

Just remember that the .bat or .cmd file you create needs to be UTF8 encoded. There used to be some issues with the batch files if they are not UTF8.

**UPDATE**

I decided to update the answer, because it would have been too long for a second comment. I want to first make clear that I do not intend to offend anyone and the next is just mine personal view and thoughts.

Well, I mine vision might be (**is**) distorted through mine prism. But, I think that these specifics has nothing to do with Windows Azure itself.

These are OS related configuration specifics and the approach would be one and the same (with some variations) regardless of a (hosting/cloud) provider. If you had to deploy your solution to a dedicated (or virtual) server, you would had to create some kind of scheduled task, or startup task to make these configuration changes. Or even interactively login to make these changes.

Since Windows Azure offers the StartUp Task, it is up to us (developers) to decide what to do and how to shape the OS according to our needs.

The OS configuration changes that one can possibly need are only limited by the total ammount of all available Windows Server 2008/R2 configuration options. I personally do not believe that these needs to be reflected in Windows Azure documentation by any means. They have their place in Windows Server documentation. It is arguable which are "commonly used", because what might be common for one, might also be "never needed" for others ...

Comment: Yes, a good option, works perfectly with Selenium. But maybe Armchair Bronco has something that works only with IE.

Comment: Astaykov is correct. We have a 3rd party DLL called WebsitesScreenShot.dll that relies on MSHTML.dll and/or SHDOCVW.dll, which are tied to IE. What surprises me about questions in this "space" is that it seems like changing IE security settings or doing other configuration tasks is something that ought to be integrated directly into the Azure portal...but it's not. Also, I'm also disappointed that MSDN doesn't have more step-by-step instructions for change the Azure configuration from a command line.  As always, StackOverflow to the rescue!

Comment: I just read astaykov's additional feedback and have to admit that he has a good point. There are so many possible settings for an Azure-based server that it would be impossible to pick up subset of "things" that would please everyone all the time with shortcuts from the admin tool. Having said that, I still think there are opportunities for someone (writer @ MSFT?, bloggers?) to give more examples for changing these settings in Azure. In my experience there just isn't a lot of good stuff out there. And setting up IE security settings on an Azure box *seems* like it would be fairly common.